# Exception handling for maximum LImit of ram +swap memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, data-structures

I have written a prog which is running under centOS. My ram +swap memory is of 16 GB.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<new>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;
int main ()
{
  std::list<double> mylist;

  double i;
  try{
    for (double i=1; i<=250000000; ++i) mylist.push_back(i); 
   }
  catch (std::bad_exception& ba) {
        cout << "Allocation failure: " << ba.what() << endl;
    mylist.clear();
        exit(1);
   }
    mylist.clear();

//  std::cout << "mylist contains:";
//  for (it=mylist.begin(); it!=mylist.end(); ++it)
//    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
//  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

My problem is when the prog runs and crossed the memory allocation for RAM area then the memory allocation takes place in swap memory. When the swap memory is full then the OS kill the prog. What type of execption handling i should use which makes my program to fill upto the available memory and hence not killed by OS.

Comment: XY-problem? _Why_ do you need to use up all memory?

Comment: Note: If your your system only has few free memory left, exception handling itself might not work, as "The memory for the exception object is allocated in an unspecified way" [except.throw]/4. Memory pages for the stack typically will only be committed when necessary (another possible problem), so best way I think is not to try to use up all the memory. Allocating big chunks might also help.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is "Don't write code that uses huge amounts of memory when there isn't enough available", but that's of course much easier to write than to actually implement if you actually NEED a lot of memory in your code.

The problem you are seeing is called "memory overcommit" and "OOM-killer". Memory overcommit is a case of your application asking for memory that doesn't really exist. A bit like airlines selling a few extra seats on a flight, in the expectation that some passengers (statistically) don't show up. In a similar way, when your application (or any other one) asks for memory, the OS assumes that they are actually not going to need exactly ALL of the requested memory, so it allows for more memory to be allocated than there is actually available.

Sometimes, however, the system then runs COMPLETELY out of memory, and the only way that the system can stay alive (which is a better option than crashing and rebooting the system) is by killing some process. It has some "rules" about what to kill - basically, first look at processes using a lot of memory, and among those, the ones that have been growing the most lately are killed first. Since your process probably satisfies that criteria quite well, it is likely to be the one killed, and since it's using a huge amount of memory, there is no need to go further.

There really isn't much you can do to stop this from happening. You could reconfigure your kernel without OOM-killer, but chances are that your system will then "OOPS" and reboot, which isn't a better alternative [unless you are actually trying to cause a system crash, but I expect you are not really wanting to do that]. 
As @Stefan says, you are probably asking for the solution of a different problem than the "real" problem, which means my answer is probably that THAT helpful to you.